# SilverStripe GridField: too many versions of DataObject get created

Tags: silverstripe

***TL;DR** When creating/saving a versioned DataObject with relation to some page, two entries are created in the corresponding versions table (instead of one).*

I'm trying to version some DataObject and have the Versioned extension applied as follows:

```php
class Testobject extends DataObject {
    static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'Page'
    );
    static $extensions = array(
        "Versioned('Stage', 'Live')",
    );
```

Testobjects are being managed in a GridField on some page like so:

```php
class PageContent extends Page {
    public static $has_many = array(
        "Testobjects" => "TestObject"
    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
        $gridField = new GridField(
            'Testobjects',
            'Testobject', 
            $this->Testobjects(),
            $config);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $gridField);
    }
```

Now, whenever i add or save some Testobject in the GridField's EditForm, **two** new entries show up in the Testobject_versions table. For comparsion, when i save a page in the SiteTree, only **one** entry in the corresponding versions table is created.

As there will we thousands of these DataObjects on a page, i'm worried about this duplication filling up my database. Is there a way to get around this?

**Further recognitions:**

- On creation of a new Testobject, the first entry in the versions table has it's PageID field set to 0, the second entry has set the actual PageID of the corresponding page.
- If I replace `$this->Testobjects()` in the GridField construction by `Testobject::get()`, only *one* entry shows up in the versions table.
- onBeforeWrite is called twice when using `$this->Testobjects()`

So it seems setting the relation to the page happens after a first 'write()', then another 'write()' is called. But where in the code does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing your page/testobject in the main section of the CMS (@ '/admin/pages'), you can try this somewhat hackish trick in your TestObject class

```
public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->push( new HiddenField('PageID','PageID', Controller::curr()->CurrentPageID());
    return $fields;
}
```

This is not ideal for the following reasons:

- hard to test with unit test controller
- awareness of the controller in the model is bad
  IMHO

But it can be a reasonable fix if it works for you

Comment: i'm inside a modeladmin, but tried your solution anyway (setting a fixed PageID as the HiddenField's value for now), but unfortunately, that didn't help